# Mistake in Khinchin's "Continued Fractions"

Tags: continued-fractions

I am reading Khinchin's *Continued Fractions* page 10.

$\lbrack a_1;a_2,a_3\ldots\rbrack$ is a continued fraction and $q_k$ is given by $q_k=a_kq_{k-1}+q_{k-2}$. Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges so that there is a $k_0$ for which $k\ge k_0$ implies $a_k<1$.

Khinchin says "for $k\ge k_0$ we have $$q_k<\frac{q_l}{1-a_k} \, (*)$$

where $l<k$."

Problem: Since $a_k\to0, $ the right hand of $(*)$ side tends to $q_l$, which is fixed. However the left side tends to infinity. Since $q_k$ is a growing sequence, this cannot happen.

Comment: Why does $a_k\rightarrow 0$? In the usual definition, they are arbitrary integers. In the generalized definition, they can be any complex numbers but again, there's no requirement that they go to 0.

Comment: $a_k \to 0$ since the given series converges.

Comment: On page 1, Khinchin says we assume $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are positive integers.

Comment: @TheSubstitute For the purposes of this proof, there is no requirement that $a_n$ be an integer, only positive.

Comment: I agree. Whether or not $a_k$ is an integer, I don't see how $(*)$ can hold for any $l<k$.

Comment: @TheSubstitute In the case that $a_k < 1$, the sequence $\{q_n\}$ does not necessarily grow to infinity (imagine the $a_k$'s decrease very rapidly to $0$).

Comment: @ErickWong, what if $l=1$? Then we'd have that $q_n$ is actually decreasing.

Comment: @TheSubstitute I understand your question now, and have an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bit of a looseness, perhaps in translation.  The quoted inequality is not meant to be universally quantified in $l$.  If you read the two paragraphs leading up to it, they show that either $q_k < q_{k-1} / (1-a_k)$ or $q_k < q_{k-2} / (1-a_k)$.

Thus the author simply means to say that $(*)$ holds for **some** $l < k$.  If you read the inequality that follows you'll see it is applying this inductively to connect $q_k$ further back to a term earlier than $q_{k_0}$.  This repeated application wouldn't be necessary if $(*)$ were true for all $l<k$.

Comment: @ Erick Wong: Original Russian text is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Khinchin's text is indeed a bit confusing -- same goes for Russian original as well. On one page he says he is going to consider only integer values of $a_k$ but in this theorem it is kind of obvious that the proof is valid for any sequence of positive real numbers $a_k$. A meta-explanation of why we should (at least for this theorem) think of $a_k$ as real is clear -- if they are positive integers (as is the case with standard continued fractions) then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ always diverges and that condition is basically pointless.